# Call static method from a header inside another header

Tags: c++, include, static-methods

I was wondering if there is a way in C++ to call a static method from a class when including the header from another class?
My implementation is more complex than the example below but I hope this can explain it better:

#### `A.h`:

```
class A
{
public:
    static void myMethod(int a, int b){std::cout << a+b << std::endl;}
    /* other stuff */
}
```

#### `B.h`:

```
#include "A.h"
class B
{
    /* class definition  */
}
A::myMethod(4,5);
```

So that in `main`, when I include `B.h`, the method from class `A` is called:

#### `main.cpp`:

```
#include "B.h"
int main(void)
{
    /* value "4+5" should already be in console output */
    /* do other stuff */
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

In order to avoid the xy-problem, here is a more detailed explanation: 
I'm developing a library which has one base class and many child classes derived from this. 
This child classes get mapped with a string as key and a `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>()` as values.

Now I have the situation that the user should be able to define its own child-classes (as headers) but not change the source code of the library. 
So when the user creates a new .h file and it gets included, I'm trying to add the new child-class to the `unordered_map<string, child-class>` directly when including the child-class header.

#### `A.h`:

```
class A
{
public:
    static bool addNewChild(const std::string name, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> input_ptr);
    /* other stuff */
private: 
    static std::unordered_map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> > myHashMap;
}
/*initialize pointer with library child-classes */
std::unordered_map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> A::myHashMap
({
    {child_1, std::make_shared<ChildClass_1>()},
    {child_2, std::make_shared<ChildClass_2>()},
    /*...*/
})

bool A::addNewChild(const std::string name, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> input_ptr)
{
    /* check if name already in map */
    /* ... */
    /* perform mapping */
    myHashMap[name] = input_ptr
};
```

#### `B.h`:

```
#include "A.h"
class B
{
    /* class definition  */
}
A::addNewChild("Child_B", std::make_shared<B>());
```

So that in `main`, when I include `B.h`, the method from class `A` is called:

#### `main.cpp`:

```
#include "B.h"
int main(void)
{
    /* at this point, child class B should have already be added to myHashMap */ 
}
```

Comment: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 A::myMethod(4,5);

Comment: you want something to be printed on the screen when a header is included?!?

Comment: can you please explain what you actually want to achieve by doing that? What you want to do isnt possible exactly like you wrote it, but there might be a different way to get what you want. See also [what is the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks @user463035818 for the remark, I just added an edit to the original answer

Comment: You cannot execute code outside of a function or a member-function or a global/static initialization. If you want to add a "new child" you need to call it explicity or create an instance of an object that has a method to add that child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot call the static C++ method when you include the header (your question is ill-formed), simply because `#include` statement is processed by C preprocessor, before the actual executable is created. What you can do is to force a call to some static methods before entering the main function by creating `static const` initializers:

```
//  some header with BaseClass
class BaseClass {

};

//  A.hpp
class A
{
public:
    static bool addNewChild(const std::string& name, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> input_ptr) {
        myHashMap.insert({name, input_ptr});
    }
    static size_t getSize() {
        return myHashMap.size();
    }
    /* other stuff */
private: 
    static std::unordered_map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> > myHashMap;
};

// A.cpp

std::unordered_map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> > A::myHashMap;

//  B.hpp

struct BInitializer {
    BInitializer();
};

class B: public BaseClass
{
private:
    static const BInitializer initializer_;
};

// B.cpp

BInitializer::BInitializer() {
    std::cout << "BInitializer" << std::endl;
    A::addNewChild("Child_B", std::make_shared<B>());
}

const BInitializer B::initializer_ = BInitializer();

// some test written with googletest
TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    std::cout << "main start" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "map size: " << A::getSize() << std::endl;
}
```

I used the gtest framework to demonstrate that `BInitializer` constructor is called before environment setup. Possible output:

```
BInitializer
Note: Google Test filter = xxx.yyy
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from xxx
[ RUN      ] xxx.yyy
main start
map size: 1
[       OK ] xxx.yyy (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from xxx (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

If you do like this, every executable linked against `B.cpp` (you need to include `B.hpp` as well of course) will call the constructor of `BInitializer` before entering the `main` function.

It is kind of hacky solution, but I hope it serves your purpose. If you can avoid using it, I recommend you not to use it.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you very much I spent days on this!